# Can SASS automatically reuse colour variables across multiple components?

Tags: html, css, sass

In my project I have a series of colours which are reused in several places around the site and set as variables. In the HTML they are a class on the element.

I have SASS files for each component, so I end up with multiple places in my code where I have to list out the different colour variations. When I add a new colour option, I need to also add a block fo the new colour to multiple components.

Is there a way to automate this, so that just by adding a new colour variable, a new block is created in each of the components? So it will just work without having to create a new variation to every component each time?

**variables.scss**

```
$red = #f00;
$blue = #0f0;
$green = #f00;
```

**charts.scss**

```
.chart {
    &.red { border: 6px solid $red; }
    &.green { border: 6px solid $green; }
    &.blue { border: 6px solid $blue; }
}
```

**section.scss**

```
.section {
    &.red { background-color: $red; }
    &.green { background-color: $green; }
    &.blue { background-color: $blue; }
}
```

**image.scss**

```
.image {
    &.red { color: $red; }
    &.green { color: $green; }
    &.blue { color: $blue; }
}
```

**panel.scss**

```
.panel {
    &.red { border-bottom: 5px solid $red; }
    &.green { border-bottom: 5px solid $green; }
    &.blue { border-bottom: 5px solid $blue; }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your **variables.css**
you can add

```
@import 'charts';
@import 'section';
@import 'image';
@import 'panel';
```

Answer (score 0):

The @import rule is [being phased out](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import) of Sass, in its place use the [@use](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use)
instead.

I'd rename the `variables.scss` to `settings.scss` and place the colors in that file as they are not variable and are a global setting.

There should be an overall file that compiles all your Sass into one, usually called `Application.scss` or `styles.scss` but you can call it whatever you like. List all the files you would like to compile in this file.

So `Applications.sccs` would look like:

```
@use 'settings';
@use 'charts';
@use 'section';
@use 'image';
@use 'panel';
```

Make sure `settings` that has the colors is listed at the top to ensure the cascade of code into the flow of files.

Comment: My CSS is already combined ok, the problem is more that I don't want to have to add a variation everytime, ideally, I'd just add a colour and the extra code would be generated automatically